# Angular Mat Paginator: how to prevent page change or page size change?

Tags: angular, events, angular-material, paginator

It looks like MatPaginator only notifies once such a change has been made by the user (PageEvent events).

Is there also a way to reject a page change, or a change on the page size?

It might be useful if some edits have been done on the page, and that - if the user tries to go to the next page - we want to offer the user the option to stay on that page to avoid losing these changes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like there's anything out of the box, as the paginator sets its own value for pageIndex rather than just outputting it for you to set using the pageIndex input. I don't like to make my components this way, as your child state and parent state can get out of sync, but having said that, you can achieve this using a ViewChild.

See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-twcg4f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) StackBlitz for implementation details.

The code is as follows:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  pageIndex = 3;

  confirmPageChange(pageEvent: PageEvent) {
    // throw up a modal for confirmation

    // prevent or allow page change by setting pageIndex property directly on the paginator
    this.paginator.pageIndex = 3; // or pageEvent.pageIndex
  }
}
```

```
<mat-paginator [pageIndex]="pageIndex" [length]="10000" (page)="confirmPageChange($event)"></mat-paginator>
```